# Как производить вычисления на внешнем сервере что бы ускорить определенные вычисления, программу или даже всю систему?

Tags: сервер, сеть

Где то слышал что например очень сложные вычисления большие компании делают на внешних серверах или как можно использовать несколько внешних разных устройств а точнее использовать их вычислительные способности для решения определенной задачи. Как это называться и где искать информацию по этому поводу? Возможно ли ускорить свое устройство с помощью отсылки части задач на внешние компьютеры использовать их как еще одно ядро процессора (если я правильно вообще выражаюсь)

Comment: Попробуйте [tmux](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux)+[vim](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim)

Comment: Спасибо! Слышал о производительности vim. Позже по ищу информацию о обоих.

Comment: Мне одному кажется что tmux и vim - это немного не в ту степь ответ?

Comment: Распределённые вычисления? Но в любом случае задачи нужно специально готовить для этого

Comment: А при чём тут vim, я не понял...

Comment: [кластер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2))

Comment: "Распределённые вычисления? Но в любом случае задачи нужно специально готовить для этого – andreymal", немного погуглил. Кажется, да, это так называется. Спасибо. В доступное время постараюсь изучить эту тему глубже.

Comment: Сейчас даже игры умудряются на удалённые сервера выносить, почитайте про Geforce Now, например )

Comment: @andreymal Ну vim всегда кстати. Автор на python программить вроде собирался.

Answer (score 0):

Области которые занимаются данным вопросом имеют названия: Распределённые вычисления; Кластер.

Comment: Как именно это реализовать пока что не выяснил.